# Iranian Solar Hijri Calendar in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, calendar, farsi

Is there any library in python like `calendar` module for [the Persian solar Hijri calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_Hijri_calendar)
I want to print a month like this, for the Iranian calendar (solar Hijri):

```
>>> from calendar import TextCalendar
>>> print(TextCalendar().formatmonth(2021, 10))

   October 2021
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there is a module that does the job for you, but if you are interested in getting the Persian(Jalali) month days, you can use the function below:

```py
import jdatetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def get_jalali_calander(jalali_year, jalali_month):
  if jalali_month == 12:
    check_month = 1
    check_year = jalali_year+1
  else:
    check_month = jalali_month+1
    check_year = jalali_year
  days_number = (jdatetime.date(check_year, check_month, 1) - jdatetime.date(jalali_year, jalali_month, 1)).days
  df = {"Mo":[], "Tu":[], "We":[], "Th":[], "Fr":[], "Sa":[], "Su":[]}
  first_weekname = jdatetime.date(check_year, check_month, 1).strftime("%a")[:2]
  for key in df:
    if key != first_weekname:
      df[key].append(None)
    else:
      df[key].append("1")
  for i in range(2, days_number+1):
    day_name = jdatetime.date(jalali_year,jalali_month,i).strftime("%a")
    df[day_name[:2]].append(str(i))
  return pd.DataFrame(df)
```

If you tend to get Esfand's (the 12th month of the Persian/Jalali year) days in the format of a dataframe, you can call `get_jalali_calander(1400, 12)`. The result would be exactly as what follows:

|  | Mo | Tu | We | Th | Fr | Sa | Su |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
| 3 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 |
| 4 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 | 27 | 28 | 29 |